# Ios local notification at same time but different alert message for different date

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uilocalnotification

I want an example code for daily quote that get locAl notification for everyday of year with given different message/quote

Answer (score 0):

Better would be add different `UILocalNotificaiton`s  for each day in a loop, create a reference data lets say today and then loop 365 times and add one day timeInterval in each iteration register them to app, something like this

```
var messages:[String] = [/*Add messages here*/]
        var date = NSDate()
        let dayTimerInterval:NSTimeInterval = (60 * 60 * 26)
        date = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(dayTimerInterval)

    for i in 0..<messages.count
    {
        let localNotif = UILocalNotification()
        localNotif.alertBody = messages[i]
        localNotif.fireDate = date
        date = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(dayTimerInterval)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotif)
    }
```

There is another way that you can do that with one notification and that when a local notification fire and user open app then you change its message by getting its reference... but for that you would need app running. You can do this in different ways

1.Your app receive a localNotification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
        {
            notification.alertBody = "new message"
        }
```

You app launched via local notification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            if let options = launchOptions {
                // Do your checking on options here
                let notif:UILocalNotification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!
                notif.alertBody = "new alert boxy"
            }
            return true
        }
```

But in both cases there are chances you missed them as both case not guaranteed every time, so add different notifications for every day.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: Different messages for different days